# Parsing Json data, Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

In my Json I have next output

```
......
"publish_date": "2016-07-16 08:09:41"
......
```

Is it possible to parse/extract only date without time, without adjusting Json

Comment: using substring you can ignore last 8 characters.

Comment: thanks! working well `TextView txdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date_item);
        getDate = getDate.substring(0, getDate.length()-8);
        txdate.setText(getDate);`

Answer (score 0):

Using [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Example :

```
String s = "your parsed jsonObject" ;
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.parse(s));
```